# Trouble getting absolute path of a file

Tags: c#, winforms, absolute-path

I have a script editor which includes tabs. Each tab page has a header which includes the file's name. I also have the following code:

```
string fileName = tabControl.SelectedTab.Text;
string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

The above code should return the absolute path of `fileName`. However, I've figured out that it actually returns the absolute path of my script editor's .exe!

Why does that happen? I've tested it and yes, `fileName` does have the corrent file name, so why doesn't `Path.GetFullPath()` work?

Comment: You need to show us the value of `filename`.

Comment: I'll give an example of the above code: I'm working with my script editor on an file named `myprogram.c` which is in the `Documents` directory, while my script editor is in a folder inside a folder inside...you get the idea. Instead of getting `PC/MyName/Documents`, I get `PC/MyName/Documents/Folder/...(folders).../script_editor.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

You must keep information about absolute path of the file - there is no way to construct it back based on just file name.

Why [`Path.GetFullPath(fileName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not work: this method converts relative path to file into absolute based on *current working directory*. That location can change while program is running (i.e. when using file open dialog) and by default starts in your exe file directory (which usually have nothing to do with location of your text files).

Comment: Hm, this explains why `Path.GetFullPath` returned the absolute path of my script editor.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you create a [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object and use the `FullName` property.

The answer to the wonky behaviour of `Path.GetFullPath` probably lies on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but this snip alone raises red flags for me:

> The file or directory specified by path is not required to exist. For example, if c:\temp\newdir is the current directory, calling GetFullPath on a file name such as test.txt returns c:\temp\newdir\test.txt. The file need not exist.

Comment: What's wonky about it? Where else would it get a path if you don't provide one? And what is it about a path that implies that a file with that name exists in the file system?

Comment: I used this: `FileInfo filePath = new FileInfo(fileName);` and check the results with this: `MessageBox.Show(filePath.FullName);`, but it seems that it does exactly the same thing as my original code. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I would check the `Exists` property of the file info, and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to see what the program considers the current working directory.  You're trying to do a relative path it seems but it seems the problem lies is you don't have it clearly mapped out between where the program is and where the file is.